# Can't access laravel page in vagrant nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vagrant

I'm creating a development environment using **Vagrant** with this dependencies:

- PHP7;
- Nginx 1.9;
- Laravel 5.3.

The problem is when i try to access laravel url `http://advodocs.local.com/`. Chrome gives me the following message:

> The advodocs.local.com page isn't work
>
> advodocs.local.com is unable to attend to this request.

And accessing the Nginx log i've received this:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#3 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#4 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->write
2017/01/06 01:58:23 [error] 2107#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#3 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#4 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#5 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Ex...
```

The file `/var/www/public/index.php` exists.

## Describing my enviroment

My Laravel project is at the root of `var/www`, and i run the following commands to change folders permissions:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name advodocs.local.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

#### Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    # Customiza propriedades do Vagrant
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2524]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 1]
    end

    # Escolhe a box
    config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'

    # Configura port forwarding
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.68.20"

    #Inicia o provisionamento
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/init.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/php.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/postgres.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/nginx.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/node.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/git.sh"

end
```

Obs: Laravel project is at the root of /var/www

Repository link [here](https://bitbucket.org/advodocs/advodocs)

Comment: You need to point  `root /var/www/laravelprojectname/public;`, and another thing did you run `composer install` at first?

Comment: @Troyer laravel project is at the root of www.

Comment: @Troyer I'm using Laravel 5.3, so `storage` folder is at root folder. And i've runned `chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage` and the problem continues.

Comment: touch /vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log && chmod 775 /vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log  should help with your error message

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov Doesn't work.

Comment: what is output of ls -l /vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log ?

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Jan  6 13:33 vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log @IuriiDrozdov

Comment: Try to create a raw index.html on /var/www/ and place something random inside and try to access to make sure your web service is working.

Comment: @Troyer I've did this before install Laravel, and was working. After install Laravel i've change Nginx root folder to `/public`.

Comment: @allan did you run composer install? :)

Comment: @Troyer Yes, i did it.

Comment: did you update your '/etc/hosts' file and added a line to point the IP to the site ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri `192.168.68.20 advodocs.local.com` yes

Comment: Does it really say "... page isn't work" ?

Comment: @moopet Yeah. HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: @moopet My chrome is in Portuguese. I get the message from google.

Comment: do you have these lines in your Vagrant file owner: "vagrant",
    group: "www-data",
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]?

Comment: @allan: It might be a Vagrant Synced folders permissions issue. Please take a look here http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/09/vagrant-synced-folders-permissions/

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the guys said, Vagrant is the current owner of the folders, and this mean changes on the permissions. I've just inserted a code into `Vagrantfile` to change the owner of some folders:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant",
owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"

config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www",
owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
```